# Basics of batteries

Tags: voltage, batteries, current

What are the electrical properties of a battery besides its internal resistance?
Does it have any capacitance associated with it? What makes a battery different from other electrical or electronic components?

Comment: It depends on the depth of your requirements.  For very basic, low power circuits you can get away with modelling it as a voltage source.  A step up has the series resistance included.  Since the battery is made of physical components, it of course has inductance, capacitance, various distributed resistances, etc.  And these all vary with frequency too but they're likely to be walled off behind regulators and so forth from the parts of your circuit that really care about that.

Comment: *What kind of electrical component is a battery?* Uhm, a **battery**? If you disagree, explain how a battery is not an electrical component.

Comment: For a short time (say, over 10% of its capacity or less) think of it as a Thevenin voltage source (a voltage source with a series resistance). Over most of its capacity, you can gradually increase that resistance to model its changing condition.

Comment: A battery is a "DC voltage source" and real batteries have a small inherent output impedance.

Comment: You can model (=imagine) the charge storing process that its a capacitor with special insulator material between the plates. That imagined special material has non-linear permittivity which depends on the cumulated density of the space dipole moment. The capacitance grows as the accumulated charge grows, so there can be only a slight voltage rise when the accumulated  charge for ex. doubles.

Comment: Someone with poor English or Engineering skills has closed the question, so I can't add an answer, but this link has some Battery Equivalent Circuit diagrams and discussion: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0360544217317127

Comment: It's a DC power source.

Comment: Helpful ,- http://www.batteryuniversity.com

Answer (score 4):

> Which are the electric properties of a battery besides its electric resistance?

Well, voltage is rather an important property.  The capacity (usually measured in amp-hours) is rather important too.

> Does it have capacitance and it charges/discharges like a capacitor or what?

If it's a rechargeable battery then you can charge it.  But the similarity to a capacitor ends there.  None of the equations for a capacitor work for a battery.

> What kind of electrical component is a battery?

It's a battery!